# Can Sphinx query push Integer patterns?

Tags: sphinx

In regex for instance if I wanted to search on up to five digits in front of my term I'd do

[0-9]\d{0,5} (Term)

can I do this with Sphinx and if so how would I return the fact that I matched Term AND the specific integer as well?

Comment: Out of interest why do you use [0-9] and \d in the regex, they mean the same thing. You could write yours as `\d{1,6}`

Comment: @barryhunter Thanks for the heads-up Barry I wrote a # of complex regex from scratch not knowing Regex at all so probably retained some mistakes a long the way. I'll clean up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sphinx doesnt have a digit only wildcard.

There are wildcards, 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-infix-len
but they match any char in charset_table.